What are necessary and sufficient conditions to have a negative cycle in a directed graph with some negative edges?
Trying to test Johnson’s algorithm with over 100 vertices but it doesn’t work if there is a negative cycle. So I’m trying to write code to construct graphs with some negative weights (about 10% of the edges) that have NO negative cycles (so that I can test the efficiency of Johnson’s algorithm).
I’m having trouble trying to piecemeal together these graphs. So I really should first try to understand what conditions create negative cycles (beyond having at least one negative edge), but having trouble finding any info in the literature.
Any insights or even reference suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

"So I really should first try to understand what conditions create negative cycles" - is that your question essentially? If so, the answer is the definition of the negative cycle - a cycle with negative sum of all weights

That only states what a negative cycle IS. I don’t know what conditions make one. I’m aware that there needs to be at least one negative edge, but that in itself isn’t sufficient to guarantee a negative cycle.

And to be specific, I’m trying to use this knowledge to create a graph that DOESN’T have a negative cycle. So perhaps I should have asked about that more specifically…

Are you looking for an algorithm to generate a graph that has no negative cycle? If so, take a graph with all weights positive. Otherwise, specify the exact problem, please

I stated the exact problem above: I am trying to create a directed graph with negative edges that has no negative cycles. Sorry, I thought I was clear about that, but I suppose the title is written differently (because I wanted to construct the algorithm myself, but at this point, I'll take help with that!).

Note that to answer the title of the question, a definition of a negative cycle suffices, as the definition of $X$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $X$ to occur. As for the algorithm, I provided one in an answer

You can, for example, do the following:

Generate a random graph with like $10$-$11$% negative edges.

Find all cycles in your graph. (This is a  standard problem, easily googlable).


For each cycle $G_i = (w_i, V_i, E_i)$:

Find $\text{sum}(G_i)= \sum_{e \in E_i} w_i(e)$, which is the sum of weights in a cyle
If $\text{sum}(G_i) < 0$: add $|\text{sum}(G_i)|$ or $|\text{sum}(G_i) + \text{whatever_positive_value_you_want}|$ to the weight of an arbitrary edge on that cycle.

That will fix all the negative cycles. Since the number of negative cycles can be exponential, the algorithm above is asymptotically optimal
